# Twilio - Clarification on the number of Whatsapp messages that the sandbox can handle

Tags: twilio

I would like to build an app with twilio that requires to send the same message to 10 people at the same time.
However, on the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api) it is said:

> Sandbox numbers are restricted to 1 message every 3 seconds.

So, does it mean that if I send the text: "Hello" to then person, the last person will receive the text after 30 seconds or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You're restricted to send a message at a time.

One thing, If you are using Twilio's WhatsApp sandbox then you can't send a free-form message like "hello". You can only able to use their pre-approved message template.

There are 2 reasons:

1. You are trying to send a message to a user who has not joined your sandbox.
2. You are sending a free form message outside the WhatsApp session to the user. A WhatsApp session lasts for 24 hours after the last inbound message you receive from a user. Outside a WhatsApp session, you may only send a pre-approved template message to the user, any message that doesn't match a pre-approved template will be sent by Twilio as a free form message. See a list of templates pre-approved for the sandbox [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#templates-pre-registered-for-the-sandbox)!.

For more details, you can see this FAQ https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/best-practices-and-faqs#sandbox